# Java; Update second ComboBox after selection in first ComboBox

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I've been trying to get te grips of Java (just because:)). At the moment I'm stuck on a 'calculator'. My intention is to select a overall subject through a ComboBox after which a second ComboBox shows which units can be calculated for said subject.

My problem is that the second ComboBox does not update and I'm having a hard time finding my oversight. Is anyone able to show my where I'm going wrong?

*note: The terms for unitstring are placeholders for the time being:).*

```
public class UserInterface implements Runnable{

    String unitstring = "Select a subject";

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Radiation Calculator 2.0");
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350, 250));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        createComponents(frame.getContentPane());

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void createComponents(Container container) {
        GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(4, 2);
        container.setLayout(layout);
        JLabel subject = new JLabel("Select a subject");

        String[] subjectStrings = {"Wavelenght", "Radioactive Decay", "Radiation Dose"};
        JComboBox subjectsel = new JComboBox(subjectStrings);
        subjectsel.addActionListener(this::actionPerformed);

        JLabel unit = new JLabel("Select a unit");

        String[] unitStrings = {unitstring};

        JComboBox unitsel = new JComboBox(unitStrings);

        JLabel input = new JLabel("Select a input");
        JTextField userinput = new JTextField("");

        JButton calculate = new JButton("Calculate");
        JTextArea result = new JTextArea("");

        container.add(subject);
        container.add(subjectsel);
        container.add(unit);
        container.add(unitsel);
        container.add(input);
        container.add(userinput);
        container.add(calculate);
        container.add(result);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JComboBox cb = (JComboBox) e.getSource();
        int print = cb.getSelectedIndex();
        System.out.println(print);
        unitArray(print);
    }

    public void unitArray(int x) {
        if (x == 0) {
            unitstring = "Lambda";
        }
        if (x == 1) {
            unitstring = "Bequerel";
        }
        if (x == 2) {
            unitstring = "Gray";
        }
        System.out.println(unitstring);
        }
}
```

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but what do you want to happen with the second combo, `unitsel`, after you make a selection in `subjectsel`?

Comment: It probably isn't your ignorance but my lack of codingskill. 'unitsel' should be updated with an array containing units appropriate to the 'subjectsel'.

Comment: List displayed by a combo is in its model. Method `getModel()` will return the combo's model. If you want to change the displayed list, you need to change the model - or replace it with a new model.

Comment: Aha! Thanks Abra,